# Where is PEAR in PHP5.3?

Tags: windows-7, php

I downloaded `php-5.3.27-Win32-VC9-x86.zip` from this site http://www.php.net/releases/ but I cannot find PEAR to install the extra extension. Where exactly is it?

Answer (score 0):

You cand find pear(.ini) at `C:\php\pear\`.